# running docker inside bazel test env on osx

Tags: macos, docker, sandbox, bazel

Trying to run `java_test` that runs `docker` inside `ProcessBuilder`.
To simplify the code of the test is as following:

```
@Test
public void testDockerExecutable(){
    System.out.println("======== running docker ==============");
    try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("docker","version")
                .inheritIO()
                .start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Running `docker version` straight from shell gives that output:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Fri Mar 24 00:00:50 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

But running the tests gives that output:

```
WARNING: Streamed test output requested. All tests will be run locally, without sharding, one at a time.
INFO: Found 1 test target...
JUnit4 Test Runner
.======== here ==============
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I know that I need to somehow import `docker` to the runfiles environment (just like `local_jdk` does). But how do I do that? Also - unlike jdk that only requires read permission, docker needs write permissions to it's `lib` folder.

My env is **mac os x sierra** and bazel HEAD (`68028317c1d3d831a24f90e2b25d1410ce045c54`).

tried it with `java_test`. The `"local"` attribute did not affect the failure. (tried it with both True and False).

---

### update: works on Linux

I tried running this in linux and it works well both with `"local"=True` and `"local"=False`. Seems like it's something related to mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux sandbox mounts some directories by default (citing [the docs](https://bazel.build/blog/2015/09/11/sandboxing.html)):

> We currently also mount /bin, /etc, /usr (except /usr/local), and every directory starting with /lib, to allow running local tools. In the future, we are planning to provide a shell with a set of Linux utilities, and to require that all other tools are specified as inputs.

I assume the docker binary is in one of the standard locations, and bazel finds it here.

Maybe on mac the binary is somewhere else and only exporting PATH to the test environment reveals it?

All aside, the best practice would be to make the test explicitly depend on some 'docker' target. Then bazel will make sure the binary is there. You can use [local_repository](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/workspace.html#local_repository) (or its `new_` variant) rules to hook it up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this does the trick:

> $ bazel test --test_env=PATH < target >

It will be interesting to understand why it works in linux